Is it necessary to use lazy evaluation instead of stream for lazy tree with Scheme language?
This is from one footnote in SICP:

Note that these lazy lists are even lazier than the streams of chapter 3: The car of the list, as well as the cdr, is delayed. ^[41]
[41] This permits us to create delayed versions of more general kinds of list structures, not just sequences. Hughes 1990 discusses some applications of ``lazy trees.''

The reference paper has 2 sections about lazy trees (i.e. possible infinite gametree in the paper): section 5 related with tree application and section 3 about tree structure.
The key difference is whether car part is delayed. But for one tree, if we use the structure in the paper p7 treeof ∗ ::= Node ∗ (listof (treeof ∗)) (i.e. something like (cons node-value subtrees)) and normally node-value evaluation won't be infinite to ensure accessing node value is possible, then evaluating the car part of the tree is fine. So IMHO stream can also work to implement lazy tree although it may do a bit more unnecessary computation for always evaluating car part.

IMHO the key part in paper about the relation between lazy tree and lazy evaluation is:

where “.” (function composition, a standard operator) is defined by
(f . g) h = f (g h)
...
maximize = max . maximize'
maximize'(Node n Nil) = Cons n Nil
maximize'(Node n l) = map minimize l
...
evaluate = maximize . maptree static . prune 5 . gametree
...
More importantly, lazy evaluation permits us to modularize evaluate in this way. Since gametree has a potentially infinite result, this program would never terminate without lazy evaluation.

For stream, maptree static . prune 5 . gametree will be one stream.
minimize can defined similar to maximize. In a nutshell, maximize do one possible short-circuit search for subtrees (see p20 top tree example where if the 2nd subtree has one value 0 which is less than min of the 1st subtree, then min of the 2nd subtree is less than the 1st one. So the 2nd min can't be one candidate for maximize. Then we can stop traversing the 2nd subtree, achieving one short-circuit behavior.). But this won't work for one infinite width tree with one level as one strictly-increasing sequence. So maximize is like DFS but will stop diving into one branch if that must be impossible for one candidate.
So maptree static . prune 5 . gametree is actually one finite stream. Then the normal maximize iterative procedure should work fine and lazy is still implied by stream.
Then keep recursion until reaching the leaves which must exist implied by prune, which is also shown in

just as the fact that prune looks at only part of an infinite tree enables the program to terminate

So stream can work fine also.
Question:
Can stream work fine to implement lazy tree if not considering the possible overhead of always evaluating the car part?

Code implementation based on stream:
To implement the above evaluate, we need max, map, Node, maptree, static, prune and  helper basic procedures for tree.
Here max, static can be offered by lib. map can be stream-map in SICP. Node can be cons-stream. maptree is offered in paper as maptree f = foldtree (Node . f ) Cons Nil based on foldtree definition (IMHO here both Node and Cons can be cons-stream since they are just concatenating something together).

Since trees are built using Node, Cons, and Nil , foldtree must take
three arguments

Actually, foldtree is just one iterative procedure but offering modularity. Here I give one stream translation of prune which is also one iterative procedure based on map

prune 0 (Node a x) = Node a Nil
prune (n + 1) (Node a x) = Node a (map (prune n) x)

(define (prune max-depth tree)
  (if (= 0 max-depth)
    (cons-stream (stream-car tree) the-empty-stream)
    (cons-stream (stream-car tree) (stream-map (lambda (subtree) (prune (- max-depth 1) subtree)) (stream-cdr tree))))
  )

(define infinite-width-leaves
  (cons-stream (cons-stream 1 the-empty-stream) infinite-width-leaves))

(define demo-tree-with-infinite-depth-and-width
  (cons-stream 0 (cons-stream demo-tree-with-infinite-depth-and-width infinite-width-leaves)))

(define test-stream-2 (prune 10 demo-tree-with-infinite-depth-and-width))
test-stream-2
;Value: {0 ...}
(stream->list (prune 0 demo-tree-with-infinite-depth-and-width))
;Value: (0)


p.s.
Some notes about the paper
lazy



only functional languages (and not even all of them) use lazy evaluation uniformly for every function call

IMHO giving one tree lib based on stream is also fine for lazy tree.



Since each part can be thrown away (reclaimed by the garbage collector) as soon as maximize has finished with it, the whole tree is never resident in memory. Only a small part of the tree is stored at a time. The lazy program is therefore efficient.
...
Thanks to lazy evaluation, if maximize doesn’t look at all of the list of numbers, some of them will not be computed

For the 1st paragraph, that is due to lazy combined with garbage collector. Stream can also do all these IMHO.



This efficiency depends on an interaction between maximize (the last function in the chain of compositions) and gametree (the first) without lazy evaluation

i.e. the chain will generate each depth level of the gametree infinitely. But stream will only evaluate each node-value without evaluating subtrees if subtrees are not needed for the current computation goal, so stream can also do that.



Thanks to lazy evaluation, the fact that maximize' looks at less of the tree means that the whole program runs more efficiently

maximize' implies lazy by dropping some subtrees based on checking the static value (i.e. "the true value of the positions" to help deciding how gametree grows) relation with minleq.
Since rest etc can be stream, so infinite val of rest is fine if not using lazy evaluation for argument.


infinite



The function repeat is an example of a function with an “infinite” output
the function repeat used to construct infinite lists
The function integrate computes an infinite list of better and better approximations to the integral

Just like infinite stream



it doesn’t work for infinite trees, because maximize keeps on recursing until it finds a node with no subtrees
If it’s possible for a game to go on forever with neither side winning, its game tree is infinite

infinite depth



statically evaluates all the positions in the tree (which may be infinitely many)

infinite width/depth



First of all, it doesn’t work for infinite trees, because maximize keeps on recursing

since lazy is about argument evaluation instead of procedure calls.



why should we be so very careful to know in advance that the car part is finite? can we always be sure? -- we can easily be free to not have to know that with absolute certainty, and just use the lazier streams where car is also delayed. (will try to read more of your question later)

in general, SO works better with short, specific questions, focused on one specific, as simple and isolated as possible, issue. it is easier to understand and thus to answer; you get more upvotes. :) your "Can stream work fine" is way too general a question to answer. it seems to me one would have to spend quite a large amount of time writing an essay in response. I hope this doesn't slight you, this is not my intention at all. on the contrary, I would like to answer more of your questions, and I feel I can't answer this one as easily as I'd like. or something. :)

if you're interested in dealing with trees with infinite width, consult the search results for such terms as "infinite streams" with conjunction with "dovetailing", "interleaving", "diagonalization" and "Omega monad" ("omega" is just a name; "monad" just means "any type with concatMap/flatMap i.e. such that lets us enumerate its values disregarding any internal structuring, like ignoring any parens in a nested list and looking just at the elements within").

@WillNess 1. Re to the 1st comment: "why should we be so very careful to know in advance that the car part is finite?" Yes, we don't need in the general case. But here as my 3rd paragraph says, the reference paper of SICP uses that data structure which has car as the node value and that value must at last have one finite car in its innermost place so can be implemented as the stream in Scheme.


Re to the 2nd: ""Can stream work fine" is way too general" Sorry. What I meant is for lazy tree structure in the reference paper which has one given data structure so may be not that general.



Re to the 3rd: wikipedia "dovetailing" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science) means changing the visiting order from the normal DFS (implied by applicative order) to BFS which "a single step is performed for every program" (i.e. data here). This is similar to "interleaving" taught in SICP section 3.5. "diagonalization" gives almost all about matrices with only one video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMXAJpaoM1w about Diagonalization argument.


Let us continue this discussion in chat.
